# Invalid Schema Content error for drop down list in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

i am trying to build a simple registration form with react and bootstrap. I have added a couple of drop down boxes in my form where the user can select from the options. Now when i open the app in browser and choose an option from one of the drop down list, it throws an error of `Invalid Schema Content`. How can i fix this issue? Here is the validateProperty function which is causing error:

```
validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };
```

Here is the form:

```
import React from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Form from "./common/form";
import { getMovie, saveMovie } from "../services/fakeMovieService";
import {
  getSalutation,
  getTitle,
  getMember,
  getOrder,
} from "../services/fakeGenreService";

class MovieForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: {
      salutationId: "",
      titleId: "",
      name: "",
      initialname: "",
      surname: "",
      username: "",
      position: "",
      memberId: "",
      language: "",
      orderId: "",
    },
    salutation: [],
    title: [],
    member: [],
    order: [],
    errors: {},
  };

  schema = {
    _id: Joi.string(),
    salutationId: Joi.string().required().label("Salutation"),
    titleId: "",
    name: Joi.string().required().label("Name"),
    initialname: "",
    surname: Joi.string().required().label("Surname"),
    username: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Personal E-Mail address (used as user name)"),
    position: "",
    memberId: "",
    language: "",
    orderId: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const salutation = getSalutation();
    this.setState({ salutation });

    const title = getTitle();
    this.setState({ title });

    const member = getMember();
    this.setState({ member });

    const order = getOrder();
    this.setState({ order });

    const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
    if (movieId === "new") return;

    const movie = getMovie(movieId);
    if (!movie) return this.props.history.replace("/not-found");

    this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(movie) });
  }

  mapToViewModel(movie) {
    return {
      salutationId: movie.salutation._id,
      titleId: movie.title._id,
      name: movie.name,
      initialname: movie.initialname,
      surname: movie.surname,
      username: movie.username,
      position: movie.position,
      memberId: movie.position._id,
      language: movie.language,
      orderId: movie.order._id,
    };
  }

  // doSubmit = () => {
  //  saveMovie(this.state.data);

  //   this.props.history.push("/movies");
  //  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Registration Form</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.renderSelect("Salutation", "Salutation", this.state.salutation)}
          {this.renderSelect("Title(s)", "Title(s)", this.state.title)}
          {this.renderInput("Name", "Name")}
          {this.renderInput("Initial/Middle name", "Initial/Middle name")}
          {this.renderInput("Surname", "Surname")}
          {this.renderInput(
            "Personal E-mail address (used as username)",
            "Personal E-mail address (used as username)"
          )}
          {this.renderInput("position with company", "position with company")}
          {this.renderSelect(
            "I am a member of",
            "I am a member of",
            this.state.member
          )}
          {this.renderInput("Language Selection", "Language Selection")}
          {this.renderSelect(
            "Order",
            "I would also like to order the following free newsletters:",
            this.state.order
          )}
          {this.renderButton("Save")}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieForm;
```

Here is the drop down data:

```
export const salutation = [
  { _id: "1", name: "Herr/Mr." },
  { _id: "2", name: "Frau/Mrs." },
  { _id: "3", name: "keine Anrede / No salutation" },
];

export function getSalutation() {
  return salutation.filter((g) => g);
}

export const title = [
  { _id: "4", name: "Prof." },
  { _id: "5", name: "prof.h.c" },
  { _id: "6", name: "Dipl.-Kfm" },
  { _id: "7", name: "Dipl.-Kfr." },
  { _id: "8", name: "Dipl.-Ing" },
  { _id: "9", name: "Mag" },
  { _id: "10", name: "Dr." },
];

export function getTitle() {
  return title.filter((g) => g);
}

export const member = [
  { _id: "11", name: "EHMA (EUROPEAN HOTEL MANAGERS ASSOCIATION)" },
  { _id: "12", name: "HDV (Hoteldirektorenvereinigung Deutschland" },
  { _id: "13", name: "RICS (Royal Institution of Chartered Surveyors)" },
  { _id: "14", name: "Skål International" },
  { _id: "15", name: "Other" },
];

export function getMember() {
  return member.filter((g) => g);
}

export const order = [
  { _id: "16", name: "Info Friday" },
  {
    _id: "17",
    name: "Special Newsletter (breaking news, events, special topics)",
  },
];

export function getOrder() {
  return order.filter((g) => g);
}
```

Here is the form:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Input from "./input";
import Select from "./select";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
    errors: {},
  };

  validate = () => {
    const options = { abortEarly: false };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.schema, options);
    if (!error) return null;

    const errors = {};
    for (let item of error.details) errors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
    return errors;
  };

  validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const errors = this.validate();
    this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
    if (errors) return;

    this.doSubmit();
  };

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];

    const data = { ...this.state.data };
    data[input.name] = input.value;

    this.setState({ data, errors });
  };

  renderButton(label) {
    return <button className="btn btn-primary">{label}</button>;
  }

  renderSelect(name, label, options) {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={errors[name]}
      />
    );
  }

  renderInput(name, label, type = "text") {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <Input
        type={type}
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={errors[name]}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

For dropdowns you can use this code snippet

```
state = {
    account: {}
};

schema = {};

validatePropertyDropdown = (name, value) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);

    return error
      ? error.details[0].message.toString().replace(/['"]+/g, "")
      : null;
};

handleDropdownChange = (name, value) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validatePropertyDropdown(name, value);

    if (errorMessage) errors[name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[name];

    const account = { ...this.state.account };
    account[name] = value;
    this.setState({ account, errors });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently there could be something with the `renderSelect` function.
The following worked for me:

**Dropdown.jsx**

```js
const Dropdown = ({ error, label, name, options, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{label}</div>
      <select
        {...rest}
        name={name}
        className="custom-select"
        id="inputGroupSelect04"
      >
        <option selected></option>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option value={option}>{option}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**form.jsx**

```js
renderDropdown(options, label, name) {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <Dropdown
        label={label}
        name={name}
        error={errors[name]}
        value={data[name]}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
```

**whateverForm**

```js
  {this.renderDropdown(
            ["1", "2", "3"],
            "Smth",
            "smth"
          )}
```

Happy coding